# DynamoDB Conditional Expression

Tags: javascript, amazon-dynamodb

I'm working on a website right now, and I'm trying to make a conditional update request to Dynamo using the AWS SDK for Javascript However, it appears that the request is ignoring my conditional and the update occurs no matter what. I'll post the code below, but essentially what I'm trying to do is the following:

- If the new score is greater than the current score (in the database) update it, otherwise leave it be

```js
// Update method
async function updateUserStats(dynamoParams) {

    return await dynamodb.update(dynamoParams, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("err: ", err);
            return "Unable to update item. Error JSON: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2);
        } else {
            console.log("Woot: ", data);
            return "Successfully updated user! " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        }
    });
}

// QueryParams with DynamoDB Update request
{ 
    TableName: 'UserStats',
    Key: { 
        username: 'Talia' 
    },
    UpdateExpression: 'SET Cindy.score = :score,Cindy.dateCompleted = :dateCompleted',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: { 
        ':score': 50, 
        ':dateCompleted': '2017-12-99' 
    },
    ReturnValues: 'UPDATED_NEW',
    ConditionalExpression: 'Cindy.score <= :score' 
}

// DynamoDB Table

Username | Cindy
  Talia    {score: 25, dateCompleted: "2018-05-14"}
```

Comment: I have provided an answer to you below. Please also note you have another error in your code. When using `await`, you need to tell AWS SDK to return a Promise like so: `await dynamodb.update(...).promise()`.

Answer (score 0):

Per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#update-property), please use `ConditionExpression`, not `ConditionalExpression`.